# Python function that uses two different columns of a table

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a table that has one column as day of birth and another as month of birth of students. I need to transform it into their zodiac signs.

I have found a function on the internet that transforms month and day of birth into zodiac signs, but it takes inputs. What if it's from two columns of a table?

```
def signo(table): #from https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-38.php
    month = int(table.iloc[:,1])
    day = int(table.iloc[:,2])
    astro_sign = 0
    if month == 12:
        astro_sign = 'sagittarius' if (day < 22) else 'capricorn'
    elif month == 1:
        astro_sign = 'capricorn' if (day < 20) else 'aquarius'
    elif month == 2:
        astro_sign = 'aquarius' if (day < 19) else 'pisces'
    elif month == 3:
        astro_sign = 'pisces' if (day < 21) else 'aries'
    elif month == 4:
        astro_sign = 'aries' if (day < 20) else 'taurus'
    elif month == 5:
        astro_sign = 'taurus' if (day < 21) else 'gemini'
    elif month == 6:
        astro_sign = 'gemini' if (day < 21) else 'cancer'
    elif month == 7:
        astro_sign = 'cancer' if (day < 23) else 'leo'
    elif month == 8:
        astro_sign = 'leo' if (day < 23) else 'virgo'
    elif month == 9:
        astro_sign = 'virgo' if (day < 23) else 'libra'
    elif month == 10:
        astro_sign = 'libra' if (day < 23) else 'scorpio'
    elif month == 11:
        astro_sign = 'scorpio' if (day < 22) else 'sagittarius'
    return astro_sign
```

I tried using `iloc` or naming the column, but it does not work (and honestly, I don't know if it should work). 
What I get when using `iloc` is:

```
NameError: ("name 'table' is not defined", 'occurred at index CO_CURSO')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to work with the entire table in your function `signo`, you can modify it to work on a single row of your DataFrame and then transform your entire dataset using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

First let's create some sample data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(28)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "birth_month": np.random.randint(1, 12, 10),
        "birth_day": np.random.randint(1, 30, 10)
    }
)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   birth_month  birth_day
0            2         24
1           10         13
2            6         13
3            7          6
4            5          9
5            1         25
6            4         19
7            8         12
8            1         29
9            4         25
```

Then we modify the function `signo` to work row by row:

```py
def signo(row):
    month = int(row[0])
    day = int(row[1])
    astro_sign = 0
    if month == 12:
        astro_sign = 'sagittarius' if (day < 22) else 'capricorn'
    elif month == 1:
        astro_sign = 'capricorn' if (day < 20) else 'aquarius'
    elif month == 2:
        astro_sign = 'aquarius' if (day < 19) else 'pisces'
    elif month == 3:
        astro_sign = 'pisces' if (day < 21) else 'aries'
    elif month == 4:
        astro_sign = 'aries' if (day < 20) else 'taurus'
    elif month == 5:
        astro_sign = 'taurus' if (day < 21) else 'gemini'
    elif month == 6:
        astro_sign = 'gemini' if (day < 21) else 'cancer'
    elif month == 7:
        astro_sign = 'cancer' if (day < 23) else 'leo'
    elif month == 8:
        astro_sign = 'leo' if (day < 23) else 'virgo'
    elif month == 9:
        astro_sign = 'virgo' if (day < 23) else 'libra'
    elif month == 10:
        astro_sign = 'libra' if (day < 23) else 'scorpio'
    elif month == 11:
        astro_sign = 'scorpio' if (day < 22) else 'sagittarius'
    return astro_sign
```

Finally apply the function and create a new column in the DataFrame:

```py
df['sign'] = df.apply(signo, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   birth_month  birth_day      sign
0            2         24    pisces
1           10         13     libra
2            6         13    gemini
3            7          6    cancer
4            5          9    taurus
5            1         25  aquarius
6            4         19     aries
7            8         12       leo
8            1         29  aquarius
9            4         25    taurus
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming when you say table, you mean python dataframe.

You can iterate across each row using iterrows method

```
import pandas as pd
data = [{'month': 1, 'day': 10}, {'month': 4, 'day': 11},{'month': 5, 'day': 17},{'month': 11, 'day': 20}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    month = row['month']
    day = row['day']
```

And rest follows the logic to convert into zodiac signs